# How do I find a matrix for all power series solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series

What is the “matrix” for $ \frac {d}{dx} $ acting on the vector space of all power series
in the ordered basis $(1, x, x^2, x^3, ...)$?

How can I use this matrix to find all power series solutions to the differential equation $ \frac {d}{dx} f(x) = x$?

I know that my matrix is not finite, but I don't know how to represent "All power series"

(I am using UC Davis's free Linear Algebra Book, page 116 question #4.)

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow this wasn't yesterday. Anyway your matrix for differentiation is $${\bf D} = \left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}0&1&0&0&0&0&\cdots\\0&0&2&0&0&0&\ddots\\0&0&0&3&0&0&\ddots\\0&0&0&0&4&0&\ddots\\0&0&0&0&0&5&\ddots\\0&0&0&0&0&0&\ddots\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\end{array}\right]$$

Now your equation becomes to solve for $\bf f$ : $${\bf Df} = [0,1,0,\cdots]^T$$
Which has the solution $${\bf f = D}^{-1}[0,1,0,\cdots]^T$$, assuming $\bf D$ is invertible, but... well of course we know it isn't, (why?). But for example, we can use a pseudo inverse or solve the normal equations instead.

Comment: How did it take 2 years for someone to answer such a common question? It must be a duplicate?

Comment: @Jam : there are extremely many unanswered questions and they grow really fast. Chances are any given question will remain unanswered if it does not get attention within the first few days.